# Change third-party library to work on Angular website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I developed a javascript library that is imported as an external file on different websites. One of the websites is using angularjs and is having some conflicts with my JS code. I don't know angular so I don't know if what I'm asking makes any sense.

Following https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#comparing-location-to-window-location- it seems that I need to use $location instead of window.location. My question is how can I access $location as a third party JS library? If I type $location on console is not available.

Can you help please.

Comment: Maybe with `angular.element(document).injector().get('$location')` (if `angular` is accessible)

Comment: You need to be more specific about the conflict you talked about. Normally you can load any library before angular.js is loaded in the index.html and the library (=the one global variable your libary probably delivers) is addressable within the angular code. EDIT You are not forced to use $location in angular nevertheless there are some advantages using it. Anyway, using $location or not won't help you here.

Comment: Thanks guys, `angular.element(document).injector().get('$location')` was what I was looking for.